# how generate string with #define?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to auto generate string like this **cover.image_size(300x400)**
**cover** dynamic key 
**image_size** static string 
**300** dynamic number 
**400** dynamic number

i want to use **#define**

```
#define WADImageSize(Key,Height,Width) (Key @".image_size" @"("Height @"x" Width@")")

NSLog(@" %@",WADImageSize(@"cover", @"300", @"400"));
Result will be like this **cover.image_size(300x400)**
```

this work fine, but i want to use variable for "cover", "height" and "width"

im trying somthing liek this //#define DLogW(fmt,...) (fmt  ##**VA_ARGS** ) but nothing work..

```
NSLog(@" %@",WADImageSize(key, height, width));
```

any help?

Comment: So the output from this macro is a constant `NSString`?

Comment: why not make WADImageSize a function instead of a macro

Comment: I guess he won't function because it's too much overhead for what it must do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (code from crystal ball):

```
#define WADImageSize(Key, Height, Width) ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.image_size(%dx%d)", Key, Height, Width])
```

Answer (score 1):

Defines mostly are used for constants. Probably an approach like this would be better.

```
-(NSString*)WADImageSizeWithKey:(NSString*)Key Height:(NSUInteger)Height Width:(NSUInteger)Width
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.image_size(%ux%u)", Key, Height, Width];
}
```

And remember also that you cannot debug defines.

Comment: `NSUInteger` and `%d`?